# Unable to create container on Azure Blob Storage with Python

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to create a container in Azure Blob Storage. This is the code snippet -

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient

import uuid

connect_str = 'xxxxxx'

#create a container
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connect_str)
container_name = "quickstart" + str(uuid.uuid4())
container_client = blob_service_client.create_container(container_name)
```

I get the below error -

```
ImportError: No module named 'azure.storage'; 'azure' is not a package
```

I have installed azure-storage-blob package. What am I doing wrong?

The output of * python -m pip show azure-storage-blob* is -

```
(venv) C:\Users\riz\PycharmProjects\azure_blob_extract>python -m pip show azure-storage-blob
Name: azure-storage-blob
Version: 12.3.2
Summary: Microsoft Azure Blob Storage Client Library for Python
Home-page: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/master/sdk/storage/azure-storage-blob
Author: Microsoft Corporation
Author-email: ascl@microsoft.com
License: MIT License
Location: c:\users\riz\pycharmprojects\azure_blob_extract\venv\lib\site-packages
Requires: cryptography, msrest, azure-core
Required-by:
```

The output of * python --version * is -

```
Python 3.7.4
```

When I try to run the code from windows CMD i get this error -

```
azure.core.exceptions.ServiceRequestError: ("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')])",)
```

When I run the code from PyCharm IDE I get this error-

```
azure.core.exceptions.ServiceRequestError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001EEA3C9AC88>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions
```

Comment: I am using PyCharm. Initially I installed it form the Project Interpreter. Then I removed it and installed it again with pip install